# Javascript -Claculating time by using milisecondes

Tags: javascript

I'm using the next code:

```
    var duration = parseInt(end - start);

    var seconds = parseInt((duration/1000)%60)
    , minutes = parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60)
    , hours = parseInt((duration/(1000*60*60))%24)
    , days  = parseInt(duration/(1000*60*60*24));
```

I'm entering the next values -

```
var end = 1433696848006;
var start = 1433696847941;
```

The final result that I"m getting is 7 days - and it's wrong.

So what is wrong at this code?

Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: It's wrong - What should it be?

Comment: the value of end-start in your example is 65.  When you try to divide 65 by 86400000 (the result of 1000*60*60*24), you get 7.523148148148148e-7 (just tried it in the JavaScript debug console).  When you then do parseInt to this value, you get 7 because it treats this as if you entered the string value of "7.523148148148148e-7".

Comment: Why `parseInt` returns 7, not 0 starting at `e-7`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Math.round

```
var duration = parseInt(end - start);

var seconds = parseInt((duration/1000)%60)
, minutes = parseInt((duration/(1000*60))%60)
, hours = parseInt((duration/(1000*60*60))%24)
, days  = parseInt(Math.round(duration/(1000*60*60*24)));
```

Comment: with the smae nambers it gives me 0 at all values

Comment: Because you divide by 1000. You must specify milliseconds, as I guess, or remove this division.

Comment: @PESfcs In your example data the difference is 65 milliseconds (0.065 seconds) so 0 for all values is correct. What did you expect instead?

Comment: So what should i change in your code than? for excample if it's 65 millisecondes than it will show 1 second?

Comment: I guess -         var seconds = parseInt(Math.ceil((duration/1000)%60)) - should do the work.